# Deployment issue with deleted package references "Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be created through the API

Tags: deployment, deployment-api, deployment-error

I have package originally and deleted that in source org and trying to do deployment to the target org after deleting without that package references but still its referencing and giving deployment errors, please help[image: DEployment Errors]

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your description exactly what you did, but the situation appears to be that you've retrieved schema elements that belong to other managed packages (Cloudingo, `rh2`) or which are part of the Salesforce standard schema (`AccountTeamMember`).

You cannot deploy those elements, and will need to remove them from the source tree that you are attempting to deploy. Note that the problem is *not* references from your components to other packages; it's components you shouldn't have at all.

Comment: Sure, I am trying to deploy without them